# How to hide/unhide desktop icons in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, desktop

Is it possible to hide/unhide icons on your desktop with Python? I know a way of doing it by editing registry but changes take place after you log off and log back on. If you have any suggestion, I'd appreciate your help.